# Missing javax.cache.annotation package when compiling with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm getting some weird errors which seem to eb the result of a missing library, though I can't figure out where it's missing from as all the guides I've seen don't seem to be including anything I'm missing. I've included the AspectJ jars and I'm compiling with ajc through IntelliJ.

```
Error:ajc: can't determine annotations of missing type javax.cache.annotation.CacheRemove
when weaving type com.webbilly.dao.hibernate.GenericDAO
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=10 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

Here it specifies javax.cache.annotation.CacheRemove, but there are other files as well that are missing that I attempted to band-aid with a package from java2s, but it's still missing this one.

Comment: I am having this error too, did you resolve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include this dependency in your pom file if you are using maven OR download jar from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0 and include it in project.